# Cancel the typo in [touches-canceled]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I was adding content to the empty tag wikis for the various touch event handlers and noticed that [touches-canceled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/touches-canceled) has a typo *and* is formatted differently than its sibling tags:

- [touchesbegan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/touchesbegan)
- [touchesmoved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/touchesmoved)
- [touchesended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/touchesended)

The method is spelled `touchesCancelled` in iOS UIKit and `TouchesCancelled` in Xamarin.iOS UIKit.

For consistency and accuracy, the tag should probably be [touchescancelled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/touchescancelled)

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me just how bad people can be at spelling tags for these things.

Comment: In the creator's defense, "canceled" is a perfectly legitimate spelling in American English. Who does Apple think they are to dictate the spelling rules of their API, anyway?

Comment: @CodyGray I was surprised that the methods used the British English preferred spelling. Now I'm reading about American vs. British verb morphology. SO tricked me into learning something and I'm not sure how I feel about that.

Comment: @Cody Gray: The tag wasn't written to resemble the method name so much as the phrase "touches canceled" in general, so I can get behind that reasoning. `touchesCanceled` on the other hand simply would not have worked correctly no matter what - had the creator written the tag to match the method name, there would have been no excuse to misspell it other than honest-to-goodness fat-fingering.